# flutter, find route name of a page using global context while using named routes

Tags: flutter, navigation

while in a specific page i need to know the name of the page, which was set by named routes. i could know with normal 'context', but i couldn't do using global context.

my code:

```
// ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name with global context, trying!
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){runApp(const MyApp()); }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); // <---
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: MyApp.navigatorKey, // set property // <---
      //home: const HomeScreen(),
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {  // ---------------> hash routing
        '/home':(context)=> const HomeScreen(),
        '/details':(context)=> const DetailsScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState!.context =context,
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Page'),backgroundColor: Colors.blue,),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print("context: ${MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext}"); //prints: context: Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#a6af1](dependencies: [HeroControllerScope, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: NavigatorState#d0a98(tickers: tracking 1 ticker))
                },
                child: const Text('button 1.1')
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print(ModalRoute.of(MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext!)?.settings.name ?? "Unknown"); //prints: Unknown
                },
                child: const Text('button 1.2')
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print("${ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name}"); //prints: /home
                },
                child: const Text('button 1.3')
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              // onPressed: () {
              //   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              //           settings: const RouteSettings(name: "/detailsScreen"),
              //           builder: (context)=> const DetailsScreen())
              //   );
              //   //Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> const DetailsScreen()));
              // },
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/details');
              },
              child: const Text('go to details page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Dispose called");
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DetailsScreen> createState() => _DetailsScreenState();
}

class _DetailsScreenState extends State<DetailsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Details Page'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print("context: ${MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext}"); //prints: context: Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#ebadf](dependencies: [HeroControllerScope, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: NavigatorState#5dfff(tickers: tracking 2 tickers))
                },
                child: const Text('button 2.1')
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print(ModalRoute.of(MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext!)?.settings.name ?? "Unknown"); //prints: Unknown
                },
                child: const Text('button 2.2')
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print("${ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name}"); //prints: /details
                },
                child: const Text('button 2.3') 
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in above example button 1.2 and 2.2 should print their corresponding page name.

looks like button 1.3 and 2.3 are printing as expected. but

```
ModalRoute.of(MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext!)?.settings.name
```

is sending null value.